# Inno-Setup Semicolon missing

Tags: inno-setup

I have the following function which results in an "Semicolon missing." error", but I don't see why.

Thank you for the help!

```
 function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
begin
   if not IsServiceRunning('oscmaintenanceserver') then
       begin
           MsgBox('Service not running. Exit.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
           exit;
       end
   end
   if not StopService('oscmaintenanceserver') then
       begin
           MsgBox('Service couldnt be stopped.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
           exit;
       end
   end
   if not RemoveService('oscmaintenanceserver') then
       begin
           MsgBox('Couldnt remove service.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
           exit;
       end
   end   
   begin
       MsgBox('All went fine :-).', mbInformation, MB_OK);
       exit;
   end
end;
```

Comment: 1- Each 'end' pairs with a 'begin', you've got a lot more 'end's. 2- Statements end with a ';', you have to put a semicolon after the remaining 'end's.

Comment: Thank you, you can make your reply the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. You go ahead if you want.

Comment: You need to change your reply to an answer, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got an extra `end` in each `if` branch. Additionally, when marking an end of a statement, an `end` requires a semicolon after it.

```
 function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
begin
   if not IsServiceRunning('oscmaintenanceserver') then
       begin
           MsgBox('Service not running. Exit.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
           exit;
       end;
   if not StopService('oscmaintenanceserver') then
   ...
```